I have a problem with removing an old partition made for a failed Windows installation on my iMac 2014 macOS 11.7.10
Theres really nothing more to add to the title. Here's the output of diskutility list

The partition making problems ist disk0s4. I already tried everything in the Diskutility app but I'm getting the following error. Here it's in German but it says it failed to resize disk0s3 and deleting disk0s4. I already saw several post about this problem, but none helped me. Please answer if you've got an idea how to solve this problem!

